# How do you get the Pipe Vault Frog Coin under the block in plain sight?

Tags: super-mario-rpg

There's a [Frog Coin](http://www.mariowiki.com/Frog_Coin) in the Pipe Vault stage of *Super Mario RPG: Legend of the Seven Stars* that is in plain sight, but under a block that Mario cannot duck under. How do you get this coin?

Comment: A picture would make this question much better.

Comment: Is this the spot you're thinking of? http://shrines.rpgclassics.com/snes/smrpg/images/hc14.jpg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the same old Super Mario run-and-duck trick works: run at the block using Y on your controller then press and hold down on the D-Pad just before running into the block.

Comment: Wouldn't pressing "down" just move you down?

Comment: It functions differently in this context, but that's part of why it can be frustrating to do.

Comment: This works on the Switch enhanced remake. Just press down on the left stick or the d-pad in front of the frog coin while moving towards it to have Mario slide. No need to push the Y button at all.